# While loop became slower after some recursions in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which uses a while loop to iterate to each record
and do some calculations. The stored procedure has the following logic:

1. Inserts some records from `old_table` to `new_table` for a specific range
   (7.8 million records) . insert took 4 minutes.
2. Then it copies records which have amount > 100 into a `temp table` 
   (37 000 records).
3. create `clustered index` on the id column of `temp table`.
4. start the while loop to iterate to each id column in `temp table` (total 37 000  records).
5. for each iteration a stored procedure is called inside the while loop.

The Sp works fine (faster) Up to 5 000 records (it completes in 5 mins)
but after 5 000 there is a delay in processing records. The delay occurs after processing each 100 records. Is there any reason for this delay?

sample structure of the stored procedure:

```
use my_db
go

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[usp_datacopy]') IS NULL -- Check if SP Exists
EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_datacopy] AS SET NOCOUNT ON;') -- Create  dummy/empty SP
GO 

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_datacopy]
@Startdate datetime, 
@Enddate   datetime, 
@Percent   int       
AS
BEGIN   
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @PerVal NUMERIC(10,2) = @percent /100.00,--Get the percent value for input.
        @wkstartdate     DateTime,
        @wkenddate       Datetime,
        @OfficeID        int,
        @id              int = 1,
        @spcount        int ,
        @rdate           datetime,


IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB..#temptable') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temptable 


INSERT INTO [dbo].[new_table]
            ( TimeID, OfficeID, dateval, rHour, Complexity,RowCountval)

        SELECT TimeID + 364, OfficeID,dateadd(dd,364,dateval),rHour, Complexity , RowCountval,
        FROM   [dbo].[old_table] WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE  dateval BETWEEN @Startdate  AND @Enddate

 --select Day records with value > 100

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(order by timeid) id,TimeID, OfficeID, dateval, rHour, Complexity,RowCountval
 INTO #temptable
 FROM [dbo].[new_table] WITH (NOLOCK)
 WHERE RDATE BETWEEN @wkstartdate AND @wkenddate   
   AND RowCountval  > 100

 CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX id_index on #temptable (id)

 SELECT @spcount  = COUNT (1) from #temptable

 WHILE   @id <= @spcount   --37000 records
 BEGIN

      SELECT @OfficeID    =  officeid    FROM #temptable  WHERE id = @id
      SELECT @rdate       =  dateval     FROM #temptable  WHERE id = @id 

      EXEC CalcPercentforEachRecord @rdate, @OfficeID, @PerVal

      PRINT @ID

      SELECT @id          = @id + 1
      SELECT @OfficeID    = NULL
      SELECT @rdate       = NULL
 END                
 IF @@ERROR = 0
      BEGIN
          COMMIT TRAN;
      END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
          SELECT @@ERROR AS ERROR,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLineNo
ROLLBACK TRAN;
END CATCH
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
  END
```

Comment: please provide your sp... we don't have a crystal ball :)

Comment: Please add your execution plan.

Comment: As the other commenters have indicated, we need more information.  That said, I'll at least mention that while loops and cursors (or any form of record-at-a-time processing) are a red flag for me as far as performance goes.  Prepare to think in terms of sets and refactor your code accordingly.  With more information we may be able to give you an easier fix - or we may not, but my impression is that this problem is in an area where the ice is thin.

Comment: i have included the sample sp's pls check

Comment: ken clement, our logic requires processing of each record one by one. I have tried some set based iterations but didn't worked out.

Comment: How are you evaluating that there's a delay after 5000 records and every 100 records? Don't rely on PRINT to give you good output of this as it'll do it in batches.

Comment: yes i cant be rely of print statement. but the process is getting slower after 5000 records. Do in need to clear the procedure cache after each iteration?

Comment: you must check on your CalcPercentforEachRecord stored procedure. You can comment out the "EXEC CalcPercentforEachRecord" to check if that is the cause of the slow behavior.

Comment: could we have the code for CalcPercentforEachRecord? Also  you can replace:

SELECT OfficeID    =  officeid    FROM #temptable  WHERE id = id
      SELECT rdate       =  dateval     FROM #temptable  WHERE id = id 

with: 

SELECT OfficeID    =  officeid , rdate       =  dateval      FROM #temptable  WHERE id = id

that way you only have one select statement in the body of the loop

Comment: Instead of inventing your own cursor, you could just use cursor to iterate the temp table, but remember to use the correct settings, not just default -- and of course it would be better to get rid of the row-by-agonizing-row approach totally.

Comment: "I have tried some set based iterations but didn't worked out." doesn't mean that "our logic requires processing of each record one by one". It means that you don't know how to do it. (Yet.)